# How to upload an image to my Psql DB using jersey 2.0

Tags: java, image, tomcat, jersey, psql

I'm actually trying to send an image to my WS using jersey 2.0 and then store this one with the '`bytea`' type of `Psql`.
I am asking if it is better to convert first the picture in an array of bytes or send a String of this array or simply the picture.

Actually my `jersey` function is :

```
@Path("changePicture/{name}/{phoneid}/{picture}")
public boolean changePicture(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("phoneid") String phoneid, @PathParam("picture") String picture) 
{
    return Queries.changePicture(name, phoneid, picture);
}
```

I have tried to send an array of bytes, now I convert in String and then again in bytes but, it's not really proper.

Could you help me ? Thanks

Comment: **You should never save images in Database** !!

Comment: And where can I store those ? In a blob storage ? It's just for one image and I will loose in performance

Comment: You can store it in any location and the `path` to this `Image` in `database` , and how you are  so sure that you'll loose performance !

Comment: Psql is a command line tool, do you mean PostgresSQL?

Comment: Have a look at json attachments and multipart.

Comment: I understand what you mean but after if I need to download my image, so I'll loose in performance if I use a blob storage or something like that